# Issues including navigation properties in query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, cors, breeze

I am using Web API 2 with CORS/Entity Framework 6/Breeze.js from bower for a single page application and the breeze query is not expanding the navigation property.

I'll break it down from server to client.

// POCOs

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        ToTable("Foo");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        HasRequired(t => t.Bar).WithMany().Map(t => t.MapKey("BarId"));
    }
}
```

// Web API Config
// omitting static class and default route
// config is HttpConfiguration

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

// Breeze Controller

```
[BreezeController]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<SomeDbContext> _contextProvider =
        new EFContextProvider<SomeDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Foo> Foos()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Foos;
    }
}
```

// Front end land

// main.js

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();

var FooService = (function(breeze) {
    var service = "http://localhost:58996/breeze/Foos";
    breeze.config.initializeAdapaterInstances({ dataService: 'webApi' });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(service);
    var entityQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery();

    this.getAll = function(callback, errorCallback) {
        return manager.executeQuery(entityQuery.from('Foo').take(10).expand('Bar'), callback, errorCallback);
    };
})(window.breeze);

var fooService = new FooService();
fooService.getAll(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Fiddler shows the JSON payload:

```
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "$type":"DataAccess.Models.Foo, DataAccess",
      "Id":"10",
      "Bar":{
         "$id":"2",
         "$type":"DataAccess.Models.Bar, DataAccess",
         "Id":"12",
         "SomeData":"Hello World"
      }
   }
]
```

but `bar` is not a field of the object in the array in chrome.

---

Edit:

The solution is to add a property to hold `BarId` and set it as a foreign key.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        ToTable("Foo");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(t => t.BarId).HasColumnName("BarId");

        HasRequired(t => t.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.BarId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What leaps out at me is that you **do not have a Foreign Key (FK) property in the dependent `Foo` entity**.

You have identified the FK column in the database table ("Foo.BarId") through the `t.MapKey` expression in your mapping.

```
HasRequired(t => t.Bar).WithMany().Map(t => t.MapKey("BarId"));
```

But you deliberately did not create a corresponding `BarId` FK property in your `Foo` entity.

Entity Framework can retrieve object graphs for associations that lack FK properties. Because you told Entity Framework about the FK **column**, it can materialize both the `Foo` and its `Bar` *on the server*. That's why you see related `Bar` data on the wire.

But BreezeJS lacks access to the database ... nor should it have any database awareness at all. Breeze only knows about (through metadata) your entity type properties. Without the FK **property**, Breeze has no way to associate a `Bar` with its parent `Foo`.

BreezeJS was probably able to *materialize* the `Bar` entity in cache. I'll bet (no promise) you'll find it there if you break in the success callback and execute the following in the console:

```
manager.getEntities('Bar');
```

But to BreezeJS, this is just another entity in cache. Breeze cannot populate the `Foo.Bar` navigation property because it does not know that or how the `Foo` and the `Bar` are related. Breeze **needs the FK property to implement that `Foo.Bar` navigation property**.

This is [why we say that](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties#foreignkeys) "***BreezeJS associations must be supported by FK properties.***"

> It takes considerable skill and knowledge - beyond the scope of this answer - to work with associations that lack FK properties. You would have to maintain the navigation properties with your own code; Breeze wouldn't be able to do it. My recommendation (including to myself): don't go there.

All should be well if you redefine "Foo.cs" as

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; } // Bar nav's FK
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Btw, in case anyone wonders, CORS is not a factor in this question.

Comment: Thanks Ward! I'll give it a try when I get into the office tomorrow. I had a feeling it might be foreign key related (there is sparse information about one to one relationships in EF) since I didn't know whether it had to do with my POCO or my mapping. Are there any modifications I need to make to the mapping file or will inserting the new property be enough?

Comment: Alright here is an update. You were right I needed to have separate foreign key properties defined. I needed to change two lines in the mapping file per property. 1) Add the `Property(t => t.BarId).HasColumnName("BarId");` and 2) change `HasRequired(t => t.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.BarId);`. I'll edit that into the bottom of my question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that worked. Now you can remove `FooMap` entirely because your `Foo` and `Bar` classes conform to the default EF conventions. Of course your real app has real classes so there may be other reasons to keep the EF Fluent API mapping class.

Comment: My real app I reverse engineered the database into code first using the EF powertools. The database schema isn't quite as nice as my examples.

Comment: If You need to accociate an element from a table with a record from a View, what are your options? (It’s not possible to create foreignKey between a table and a view) @Ward