# breeze.js not honoring the "noTracking" option when end point returns multiple result sets

Tags: api, entity, breeze

Consider this breze query:

```
return EntityQuery.from('myAPI')
  .noTracking(true)  
  .using(manager).execute()
  .then(querySucceeded)
  .fail(queryFailed);
```

My API is defined like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public object myAPI()
    {
      // var userId = get the users id from auth ticket
      var userPref = _contextProvider.Context.UserPreferences.Where(u => u.userId == userId);
      var userOptions = _contextProvider.Context.UserOptions.Where(u => u.userId == userId);
      return new
      {
          userPref,
          userOptions 
      };
   }
```

I know I can get access to the raw data, which is great.  But in addition to this, the entities are created in the entity manager, which I would prefer they not be.  This works fine for apis that return IQueryable. Is there a different syntax for noTracking for web apis that returns multiple result sets?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error you describe. I have [a similar DocCode test that passes](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/queryXtraTests.js#L81) which references Breeze v1.5.3.

Here is the [pertinent NorthwindController method](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/Controllers/NorthwindController.cs#L202):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups()
    {
        var regions = _repository.Regions;
        var territories = _repository.Territories;
        var categories = _repository.Categories;

        var lookups = new { regions, territories, categories };
        return lookups;
    }
```

And here's the passing QUnit test:

```
  asyncTest('object query (e.g., lookups) w/ "no tracking" does not add to cache', function () {
    expect(2);
    var em = newNorthwindEm();
    EntityQuery.from('Lookups')
      .noTracking(true)
      .using(em).execute()
      .then(success).fail(handleFail).fin(start);

    function success(data) {
      var lookups = data.results[0];
      var hasLookups = lookups &&
                       lookups.categories && lookups.regions && lookups.territories;
      ok(hasLookups, 'Expected a lookups object w/ categories, regions and territories');

      var cached = em.getEntities();
      var len = cached.length;
      equal(0, len, 'Expected ZERO cached entities of any kind and got ' + len);
    }
  });
```

If I comment out the `noTracking(true)` clause, the test fails and tells me that there are 65 entities in cache ... as predicted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Version 1.5.3 fixed it. I was at 1.4.6.  Once I upgraded, the entities were no longer created with noTracking = true.   Note that this only happened when the API returned multiple result sets.  This also explains why I asked this questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594322/preventing-breeze-js-from-creating-observables-properties-on-array-objects .  I realize now it was the same issue.  Is it safe to assume that Observables = Entity Creation.  Meaning that when breeze returns an array of observable objects, they're probably in the entity cache.

Comment: After further testing, I had to revert back to 1.4.6.  With 1.5.3,  my "expand" queries were failing with the message "unable to locate property: A on entityType: B", where A is a navigational property.  I have FK's setup, and have the FK ID in the entity definition (as this link mentions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692463/issues-including-navigation-properties-in-query).  Works fine in 1.4.6.  I really would like to be at the latest version.  Any quick ideas?  Or should I post a new issue?  thanks

Comment: Found it. It's a case issue.  In my scenario, expand("User") worked in 1.4.6.  In 1.5.3 it has to be .expand("user").

Comment: Yup. See release notes on that one. So ... all is now well?